# Lex - yacc program showing syntax error

Tags: yacc, lex

The following two codes have been written in order to perform arithmetic operations on input , but it gives me syntax error all the time 
Here is the lex program

```
%{ 
#include "y.tab.h" 
#include <stdlib.h>
%}



%%

[0-9]+ {yylval =  atoi(yytext);return ID;}

[*-+/()] {return yytext[0];}

'\n'  {return END;}


. {return yytext[0];}

%%
```

Here is the yacc program :

```
 %{
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include "y.tab.h"     
 %}
 %token ID END  
 %%
 S: expr END { printf("Answer is : %d\n",$$);   exit(1);  }   
 expr: ID
 | 
 | expr '+' expr { $$ = $1+$3;}
 | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1-$3;}
 | expr '*' expr { $$ = $1*$3;}
 | expr '/' expr { $$ = $1/$3;}
 | '(' expr ')' {$$ = $2;}
 ;
 %%
 int main()
 {
     yyparse();
 }
```

Output:

```
 2+3

 2+3
 Syntax error
```

What could the problem be ?

Comment: You have shown the output -- that's good.  It's not clear what your input is.

Comment: 2+3 was my input ..If correct it is supposed to display:
Answer is 5

Comment: Aside from the errors I mentioned in my answer, you also need to fix the shift-reduce conflicts by defining operator precedences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems.

The first problem is that your grammar only recognizes a single expression:

```
S: expr END { printf("Answer is : %d\n",$$);   exit(1);  }
```

So if you enter two expressions, there is a syntax error.

The second problem is that your scanner does not actually recognize a newline character as an `END` token:

```
'\n'  {return END;}
```

<kbd>'</kbd> is not a special character for (f)lex. (See the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) for a complete list of accepted pattern characters.) So that rule is looking for three characters: an apostrophe, a newline, and another apostrophe. If you provide that input, you will get the "expected" output:

```
$ ./badexpr
2+3'
'
Answer is : 5
$
```

What you meant to write was

```
\n    { return END; }
```

But that's probably not ideal either. That will return immediately after a single expression. A more interesting grammar would allow for any number of expressions:

#### file.l

```
%{ 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h" 
%}

%%

[0-9]+ {yylval =  atoi(yytext);return ID;}
.|\n   {return yytext[0];}
```

#### file.y

```
%{
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
%}
%token ID
%%
S: /* %empty */
 | S expr '\n'   { printf("Answer is : %d\n",$2); }
 | S '\n'
expr: ID
 | expr '+' expr { $$ = $1+$3;}
 | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1-$3;}
 | expr '*' expr { $$ = $1*$3;}
 | expr '/' expr { $$ = $1/$3;}
 | '(' expr ')' {$$ = $2;}
 ;
 %%
 int main()
 {
     yyparse();
 }
```

#### Changes:

- I removed all of the single-character patterns from the flex input because they all have the same effect: return the single character read. That includes the newline character, because of the following change.
- I changed the start production for the grammar so that it looks for a newline character explicitly (rather than `END`) and accepts any number of input lines.
- I removed the `#include "y.tab.h"` from the bison input because it is not necessary to include the parser header in the parser file.
- I moved the empty production for `expr` into the `S` production so that it does not attempt to print the value of an empty expression.

Finally, you attempt to explicitly recognize an `END` token in your start production. That may work but it is not recommended.

Yacc/bison automatically augment your grammar by adding an outer rule which looks precisely like your rule `S`: it recognizes the start non-terminal followed by `END`. So adding your own production is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah , this worked . Thanks a lot . I assumed newline is treated as a character and lex follows the same principle to identify it .