# How does a parser solves shift/reduce conflict?

Tags: parsing, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

I have a grammar for arithmetic expression which solves number of expression (one per line) in a text file. While compiling YACC I am getting message 2 shift reduce conflicts. But my calculations are proper. If parser is giving proper output how does it resolves the shift/reduce conflict. And In my case is there any way to solve it in YACC Grammar.

**YACC GRAMMAR**

```
Calc  : Expr               {printf(" = %d\n",$1);} 
  | Calc Expr          {printf(" = %d\n",$2);}
  | error              {yyerror("\nBad Expression\n ");}
  ;
Expr  : Term               { $$ = $1;         }
  | Expr '+' Term      { $$ = $1 + $3;    }
  | Expr '-' Term      { $$ = $1 - $3;    }
  ;
Term  : Fact               { $$ = $1;         }
  | Term '*' Fact      { $$ = $1 * $3;    }
  | Term '/' Fact      { if($3==0){ 
                yyerror("Divide by Zero Encountered.");
            break;}
               else
                $$ = $1 / $3;    
                   }
  ;
Fact  : Prim               { $$ = $1;        }
  | '-' Prim           { $$ = -$2;       }
  ;      
Prim  : '(' Expr ')'       { $$ = $2;        }
  | Id                 { $$ = $1;        }
  ;
Id    :NUM                 { $$ = yylval;    }
  ;
```

What change should I do to remove such conflicts in my grammar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison/yacc resolves shift-reduce conflicts by choosing to shift. This is explained in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-shift_002freduce-conflicts-2) in the section on Shift-Reduce conflicts.

Your problem is that your input is just a series of `Expr`s, run together without any delimiter between them. That means that:

```
4 - 2
```

could be one expression (`4-2`) or it could be two expressions (`4`, `-2`). Since bison-generated parsers always prefer to shift, the parser will choose to parse it as one expression, even if it were typed on two lines:

```
4
-2
```

If you want to allow users to type their expressions like that, without any separator, then you could either live with the conflict (since it is relatively benign) or you could codify it into your grammar, but that's quite a bit more work. To put it into the grammar, you need to define two different types of `Expr`: one (which is the one you use at the top level) cannot start with an unary minus, and the other one (which you can use anywhere else) is allowed to start with a unary minus.

I suspect that what you really want to do is use newlines or some other kind of expression separator. That's as simple as passing the newline through to your parser and changing `Calc` to `Calc: | Calc '\n' | Calc Expr '\n'`.

---

I'm sure that this appears somewhere else on SO, but I can't find it. So here is how you disallow the use of unary minus at the beginning of an expression, so that you can run expressions together without delimiters. The non-terminals starting `n_` cannot start with a unary minus:

```
input:  %empty | input n_expr { /* print $2 */ }

expr:   term | expr '+' term | expr '-' term
n_expr: n_term | n_expr '+' term | n_expr '-' term

term:   factor | term '*' factor | term '/' factor
n_term: value | n_term '+' factor | n_term '/' factor

factor: value | '-' factor

value:  NUM | '(' expr ')'
```

That parses the same language as your grammar, but without generating the shift-reduce conflict. Since it parses the same language, the input

```
4
-2
```

will still be parsed as a single expression; to get the expected result you would need to type

```
4
(-2)
```

Comment: I used this thing it eliminates the shift/reduce conflict but I have a text file which will have new expression with new line in which this thing will consider the whole text as a single equation and user may or may not use ( ) in expression.

Comment: @nikul: yes, you would be better leaving your expression grammar as it was and changing your lexical scanner to return newline tokens, so that you can use the newline-delimited version of `Calc`

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42093276/1566221, but don't copy the code: OP's code has lots of problems (otherwise he wouldn't have asked :) ), and my answer doesn't deal with the operator precedence issues. But it does do newlines properly.